# categorize text with elasticsearch

Tags: java, search, elasticsearch

I am currently working on a Project which involves identifying different "keywords" out of a text.

As an example, lets assume the following input text:

> "This is an example of some text written from Buenos Aires about Meat".

Further lets assume that my elasticsearch instance has following documents stored:

> Cities: [Barcelona, Buenos Aires, Los Angeles, ...]

and

> Categories: [finance, politics, ..]

I need a way to identify from the input text the corresponding city and category.

My first approach was to do a search query with "or" operator and see which one has the highest ranking. After that I will also rematch the matched documents with the text to ensure that these texts are really there (in other words to ensure that "los angeles" matches because the word "los angeles" is in the text and to only "los" or "angeles).

I am wondering if it a best practice way of doing this kind of things with Elasticsearch.

Comment: Could you please accept the best answer you got here?

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest the following:

- use [`match_phrase`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query.html) queries to identify that the terms `los` and `angeles` exist and exist in the same order and position
- wrap each query in a [named filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/named-filters.html) so that you can identify which ones matched.

For instance, create this document:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "text" : "This is an example of some text written from Buenos Aires about Meat"
}
'
```

Then run this query looking for `Buenos Aires` or `Los Angeles`:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "constant_score" : {
         "filter" : {
            "or" : [
               {
                  "fquery" : {
                     "_name" : "buenos_aires",
                     "query" : {
                        "match_phrase" : {
                           "text" : "Buenos Aires"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               },
               {
                  "fquery" : {
                     "_name" : "los_angeles",
                     "query" : {
                        "match_phrase" : {
                           "text" : "Los Angeles"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
'

# {
#    "hits" : {
#       "hits" : [
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "text" : "This is an example of some text written from Buenos Aires about Meat"
#             },
#             "_score" : 1,
#             "_index" : "test",
#             "_id" : "JIwnN_FVTv-0i5YGrlHLeg",
#             "_type" : "test",
#             "matched_filters" : [
#                "buenos_aires"
#             ]
#          }
#       ],
#       "max_score" : 1,
#       "total" : 1
#    },
#    "timed_out" : false,
#    "_shards" : {
#       "failed" : 0,
#       "successful" : 5,
#       "total" : 5
#    },
#    "took" : 58
# }
```

Note the `matched_filters` element in the results, indicating which filter matched.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for! I will give it a try as soon as possible! Thks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this might also be a good fit for the [Percolator](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/2011/02/08/percolator.html).

You could index your queries as documents on a separate index, then percolate your documents to know which queries they match. Have a look at the [percolate API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/percolate.html).

You would need to create an index (using the [create index API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-create-index.html)), let's call it test for example:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test
```

Then register our "Buenos aires" query giving it a name. The match phrase query seems a good choice, as DrTech suggested in his answer.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_percolator/test/buenosaires -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "text" : "Buenos Aires"
        }
    }
}'
```

Then percolate, meaning that we send a document and we get back which queries it matches among the queries that we previously indexed:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/type1/_percolate -d '{
    "doc" : {
        "city" : "This is an example of some text written from Buenos Aires about Meat"
    }
}'
```

You should in this case get back the following json, where buenosaires is the name we gave to the query while indexing it:

```
{"ok":true, "matches":["buenosaires"]}
```

DrTech's answer is really good. I think the main difference is made by where your text actually is. If it's already indexed in elasticsearch, then the best strategy is to make named queries to get back which ones your documents match in a single request.

On the other hand, if you are about to index data and you need to enrich your documents before actually indexing them, the percolator is probably a better fit.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The best bet to identify "keywords" as previously indexed values and avoid cases like "los" "angeles" is to use a term facet query a non analyzed field. 
Beware of memory costs and take a look [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/terms-facet.html) for more examples.
Cheers

Comment: This would work only if you already have categories in a separate field. If you have a big text which contains name of cities, you do need to analyze it. I guess your approach doesn't fit the question.

Answer (score -2):

[Elastic search](http://www.elasticsearch.org) basically is based on top of [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org), and thus you may use any Apaches queries you would like:

[query command](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query.html) + [query syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html)

In you case I would recommend to look at "Fields" queries:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/field-query.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I know ElasticSearch and I have used it a couple of times. 
I am looking for a best practice to cover the example explained before.