# Which subquery matched out of my compound query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a nested query like this

```
{  
"fields" : ["title","wordCount"],
"query":{
    "bool":{

            "should":[
        {
            "match":{
                "title":{
                    "query": searchTerm,
                    "operator": "and"    
                }
            }
        },
                {
                    "match_phrase" :{

                        "postHtml":{

                        "query" : searchTerm,
                        "slop" : 1    
                     }

                    }        
                },
                {
                    "match":{
                        "caption" : searchTerm
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way know if there is a match on caption or postHtml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap each query into a [named filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/named-filters/); elasticsearch will give you back the name of the filters that matched.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15198481/633239) example.